Two numbering styles at the first level in the multilevel list
In Microsoft Word 365, I would like to have a multilevel list as follows:
1.HeadingLevel1
1.1.HeadingLevel2
1.2.HeadingLevel2
2.HeadingLevel1
2.1.HeadingLevel2
2.2.HeadingLevel2
A.HeadingLevel1
A.1.HeadingLevel2
A.2.HeadingLevel2
B.HeadingLevel1
B.1.HeadingLevel2
B.2.HeadingLevel2
That means, after a certain sections (after Section 2 in the example above), the numbering is switched from number style to alphabet style.
Section 1, Section 2, Section A, Section B should be exactly at the same level so that they are all shown in the Table of Contents and in Navigation Pane.
T
Their Heading Style should be also the same.
I tried all the way without success. How should I do?
Thank you very much in advance,

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community Do you mean that my question hasn't enough detail or I asked many questions? In fact, I ask just 1 question for 1 problem: "How to have two numbering styles at the same level in a Multilevel List". If I need to provide more information, just let me know.

You can define a separate set of styles for Appendix level 1, 2, etc; define them by copying the original heading styles. Then, apply a new multilevel numbering scheme to the first heading called "A." and update the style to reflect that.

You can certainly do this; I do it all the time. Define a second set of styles for the second set of headings, based on the built-in heading styles. Make sure the styles are not set to update automatically. Give the second set of headings the new styles you just created.
Then, with the cursor on the first of the headings with the new style, define a new multi-level numbering. Select "from this point forward", link each level to the new heading style, and format the list the way you want it.


Thanks Paul, it seems what I'm seeking. I can create a second set of styles or the second set of headings, based on the built-in heading styles. However, could you please give me more details for the 2 next steps  (1/ give the first headings with the new style a new multi-level numbering, and 2/ update each of the new styles )?

added a bit of detail, see if you can make this work

+1. I haven't had time to check again that. I'll do that this week-end.
